# Proving that one is unique in the set of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

$RTP$: Show through the use of field axioms that $1 \in \Bbb{R}$ is unique.

Proof : The number 1 is unique in $\Bbb{R}$ if the following two properties are satisfied, i ) $a \cdot 1 = a$, and ii ) $a \cdot a^{-1} = 1$. Let $u=1$. Assume there exists a real number $v \neq u$ such that $$a \cdot v = a \cdot u$$ By the existence of a reciprocal and the associate law of a product $$(a^{-1}\cdot a)\cdot v=(a^{-1}\cdot a)\cdot u$$

Thus we have two results $$uv=uu$$ or $$vv=uv$$ Both lead to $u=v$, which, through contradiction, must mean that 1 is unique in $\Bbb {R}$. Is there a flaw in this proof?

Comment: I don't believe that the first line of the proof is the definition of "uniqueness". And what's $a$ - if you mean "for all real $a$" you need to say so. In fact you need to state clearly what you're trying to prove. If a necessary property of "being $1$" is that for some $a$, $a\cdot a^{-1}=1$ then clearly $1$ is unique since by definition $\cdot$ is a binary operation, that is gives a unique answer.

Comment: To be clear, I think the exercise should be "Prove (using some of the field axioms) that there is one and only one element $u$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $a\cdot u =a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: but certainly the reciprocal property I mentioned must also be true?

Comment: I interpreted 'unique' in this case, to mean there is only number in reals that satisfies the properties of one - what else could it mean?

Comment: But it is necessary to say what that means, and by omitting quantifiers you've failed to do so. Anyway, since my reformulation is true there is no need to worry about inverses, that will follow for free.